# How to Get GA Sessions Data for Long List of URLs?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, google-data-studio

Suppose I have a list of 1000 of URLs of my site, and I want to get GA data for only those URLs. Is there a quick-ish way to do that?

Ideally I would be able to use this in data studio too.

Would this be a use case for the API? I'm fine with programming a solution on my own, but wanted to see if there was an easy way in GA interface.

It seems like this should be easier than creating an insanely long regex statement or entering one by one.